# Yii: How can I go on Humhub to Gii

Tags: php, yii, gii

[image: I can not go to Gii]

and this is my `main.php` in yii (humhub)

```
'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'gii',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        ),

    ),
```

What changes are needed?

Comment: @tinybyte It's a powerful open source social network, written in Yii. See https://github.com/humhub/humhub/

Answer (score 2):

You should not modify `main.php` file to enable `gii`. Please modify `_defaults.php` and add `gii` module in modules array:

```
// Modules
'modules' => array(
    'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'gii',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        ),
// All HumHub Modules will automatically loaded via
// /modules/*/autostart.php
//   or
// /modules_core/*/autostart.php
```